# C++ ABI changes

Tags: c++, g++, clang++, abi

For some reasons I need to link an executable (in Linux) which has object files compiled by different C++ compilers and versions.
I use g++ and clang (9, 10 and some older ones). May occur any compatibility issues in this scenario?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, you will certainly occur compatibility issues. The chances of getting a bug-free result from this excersize (assuming that the C++ source is bug free itself) are not very promising.

Comment: I see. Then I won't play with this kind of game. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway, the question isn't about gcc versions' compatibility, but rather in gcc-clang ang clang-clang relations.

Comment: Same thing. Your guarantee of a stable result is about 0% for anything more complicated than "Hello world!".

Comment: So a GCC question answers a clang specific one? Nice.